Having trouble getting p5.SoundRecorder to work
I have a p5.js sketch that integrates some Tone.js music functions adapted from @mattdesl
I have added a p5.SoundRecorder from https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.SoundRecorder
following is the p5.js project >> https://editor.p5js.org/gradientsASK/sketches/Bch9xA2bU
my intention is to manually stop recording and save the file by inserting code into the console while the sketch is running >>
recorder.stop();
save(soundFile, ‘soundASK.wav’);
this saves a wav file of the correct time duration, but the sound is empty.
according to SoundRecorder reference on p5js dot org “If no parameter is given, p5.SoundRecorer will record all audible p5.sound from your sketch.”
so I don’t understand why I am getting an empty silent wav file (the time duration is correct, so something is recording something, but not the sound emanating from my sketch).
thank you in advance for any assistance
I have tried running and adding the commands to console, it saves an empty/silent wav file of the correct time duration but no sound

I don't see any code. Can you [edit] the post to share a [mcve] of your code as a runnable snippet here in the question? Thanks.

sorry, here is a link to the entire project including html and js thanks. sorry, I don't know if the problem has to do with loading the packages or the actual code, hence I am referincing all thanks https://editor.p5js.org/gradientsASK/sketches/Bch9xA2bU

Thanks, but please read the link I shared. It says: "Complete: Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself". We have stack snippets that run p5.js very nicely, so it shouldn't be necessary to use an external link that can disappear at any point. If you can't make the sound export work in a snippet, that's OK--including the code as text with a link is fine too, as long as the code is here as well.

hello @ggorlen ok I understand the need for avoiding external links and apologies.

trying to insert code but it says too many characters

Try to minimize the size of the example--you should be able to get it down to a hundred or two lines of code at the most, preferably a dozen or two.
